# Firebase connection not working on Linux in SpringBoot

Tags: java, linux, spring, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

What I'm trying to achieve is to open a connection to my firebase database and get some data which i need to parse. I am running Spring with the Spring Boot framework, the admin sdk of firebase, kotlin and gradle. On Windows 10 it is working like expected, but when i try to run the .jar file on my linux server it doesn't get any data or errors. It gets stuck at the ValueEventListener. I have ufw installed, but disabling it or adding ports 5228:5230 (tcp/udp), didn't solve the problem.

```
    val dataMinifiedRef = database.reference.child("minifiedData").child("areas")
    dataMinifiedRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError?) {
            log.info(error!!.message)
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            log.info("Got data")
        }
    })
```

EDIT:
This is how I parse the service account.

```
    val str = "{\n" +
              ...
              "}\n"

    // convert String into InputStream
    val serviceAccount = ByteArrayInputStream(str.toByteArray())

    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxx.firebaseio.com")
            .build()
```

I get the following error.

```
Tue Dec 19 15:31:41 CET 2017 [DEBUG] com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection‌​: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token 
Tue Dec 19 15:31:41 CET 2017 [DEBUG] com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection‌​: pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account:
```

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong. But if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) you might get a clue in the output.

Comment: its  giving you log "got data"?

Comment: No, there is no log showing

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i set the loglevel to debug and now firebase put this out: `Tue Dec 19 15:31:41 CET 2017 [DEBUG] com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Trying to fetch auth token
Tue Dec 19 15:31:41 CET 2017 [DEBUG] com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Error fetching token: java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account:`. I have the service_account in a string, which I parse with a ByteArrayInputStream. I think this is working, but i have the assumption that it can't connect to firebase itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the time on our Linux server was not synchronized automatically. I have found this [article](https://serverfault.com/questions/885049/firebase-admin-sdk-unable-to-fetch-token) where he mentioned the solution. I have then followed this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/tips/how-to-sync-your-linux-server-time-with-network-time-servers-ntp/) and added NTP servers which are equal to our server location.